# Git pull doesn't seem to work

Tags: git, git-pull

Here's what I've done:

```
git fetch origin
git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 2 commits.
git pull
Already up-to-date.
```

But `git pull` doesn't seem to work!  This is the output I get when I try `git checkout master`:

```
git checkout master
Already on 'master'
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 2 commits.
```

Why is this? How do I fix it?

Comment: You have changes that don't exist on remote, but you *do* have all origin/master's commit.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Pull is fine; you don't have any new updates from your remote server to add to your local machine.

What you *do* have are two commits that *aren't* on `origin/master` which you should look to push.

Use `git push origin master` while on master to rectify this issue.

Comment: Or `git reset --hard origin/master` to remove your changes and sync totally with `origin/master`.

Comment: @MarounMaroun: Yes, this is true, but I genuinely doubt that the hard reset is desirable in this scenario.  I'm going to assume good faith and presume that the OP believed that they thought they had more updates to get from origin as opposed to them needing to publish their updates instead.